# Remove Unnecessary Characters while keeping CSV format using shell

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sed, tr

I have a CSV file in the following format

```
902610747280285697, possible future hurricaneirma analog 1995\xC2\xA02003\xC2\xA02004\xC2\xA02008 2010 til east leeward doubtful afterward invest93l
902611695239094277, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902642953373577216, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902711459561525248, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902755305158782976, 12z ecmwf setup support major strike east coast high east deep uul west hurricaneirma
902772740507275265, possible future hurricaneirma analog 1995\xC2\xA02003\xC2\xA02004\xC2\xA02008 2010 til east leeward doubtful
902777486186086400, future hurricaneirma satellite look impressive tropicaldepression10 24 hour
903355611810852867, hurricaneirma think f ***
903355689455804416, hurricaneirma tropics weather
903411347337162752, hurricaneirma shiiiiiiitty t *** im possibly wrong
903411365607591936, hurricaneirma 3000 mile cat 3 hurricane watch closely
903989185845088257,
```

How do i remove the the characters like *,\xC2\xA02003\xC2\xA02004\xC2\xA0 and empty rows like the last one which might throw error in the Scala processing later on.I need to maintain the CSV structure in the same manner as before but require to remove these.

Please help me to achieve this in shell script?
Thanks you once again as I am newbie in shell scripting

Edit:

Could you please tell me on how to correct the corrupted rows(with no ',') like

```
902755305158782976, 12z ecmwf setup support major strike east coast high east deep uul west hurricaneirma
902777486186086400, future hurricaneirma satellite look impressive tropicaldepression10 24 hour
903355611810852867 hurricaneirma think
903355611810852868 hurricagggneirma think
```

Comment: @AnythingIsFine,@Chintamani Manjare,@cdarke Please help me in this.Thank you once again for your help

Comment: Some explicit content over there pal.

Comment: What definition are you using of "empty row" that would include `903411347337162752    hurricaneirma shiiiiiiitty t im possibly`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed` for this but I am pretty sure, you may not get 100% results. You should use a tool native to the file that you're processing to get the results in the desired format. Anyways below is my try :

```
$ sed -E '/^[^,]*$/d;/^[0-9]+, *$/d;s/ \*+ */ /;s/\\[xX][^\ ,]*//g' case_file_48246326
```

**Output**

```
902610747280285697, possible future hurricaneirma analog 1995 2010 til east leeward doubtful afterward invest93l
902611695239094277, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902642953373577216, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902711459561525248, midlevel ridge push invest93l future hurricaneirma wsw ridge east leave som
902755305158782976, 12z ecmwf setup support major strike east coast high east deep uul west hurricaneirma
902772740507275265, possible future hurricaneirma analog 1995 2010 til east leeward doubtful
902777486186086400, future hurricaneirma satellite look impressive tropicaldepression10 24 hour
903355611810852867, hurricaneirma think f 
903355689455804416, hurricaneirma tropics weather
903411347337162752, hurricaneirma shiiiiiiitty t im possibly wrong
903411365607591936, hurricaneirma 3000 mile cat 3 hurricane watch closely
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sjsam,but like you said it is still not filtering all the characters for large file.I will try to write a script and process line by line in mean time

Comment: @Ram That sounds like a great idea. Having tools native to your specific requirements often helps..

Comment: Could you please tell me on how to delete the empty rows ?I have added example? The empty rows are not getting deleted even for the previous csv file.

Comment: @Ram  : What you mean by empty rows? `903411347337162752    hurricaneirma shiiiiiiitty t im possibly ` doesn't look like an empty row to me. At the vey first, you should put the question clearly in a way that brings about the expected requirement.

Comment: An empty row for `sed` is a blank line. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi @sjsam, In the example I have given in edit,how do i remove rows ending with id's 36 and 34?

Comment: @Ram : But it doesn't look like a CSV input to me. Are commas present after rows ending with id's 36 and 34?

Comment: @sjam ,I am trying to generate this CSV file from existing database table.I have resolved the empty rows error.But is there any way we could remove or correct the rows  67,68 in the edit to ensure the CSV file format doesn't get corrupted.?

Comment: @Ram See the edit. Note that I have added `/^[^,]*$/d;` in the beginning of `sed`.